# Asp.NET Core EF. Trying to Edit stored info

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Intro: I am a .NET studet trying to learn ASP.NET Core MVC. So please be understanding. I have searched the web for an answer to my problem, but havent found a solution that works for me.

My Problem:

I am working on a Blog. I have created a blogpost containg Header, content, categorytype and date of post. Now I want to be able to edit the post. But when I hit save cahnges button the web page refreshes and the content I modifed is gone.

My Action method:

```
  public IActionResult Edit(int PostID, [Bind("Header, Content, category")] Post post)
        {
            if(PostID != post.PostID)
            {

                return NotFound();
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Update(post);
                db.SaveChangesAsync();

                return RedirectToAction("index");
            }

            return View(post);
        }
```

My View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Blogg.Model.Post>
    @using Blogg.Model
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Skriv ett inlägg</h1>
    @foreach (var item1 in Model)
    {
        <div id="post-@item1.PostID, @item1.category.CategoryID">
            <form name="CreatePostForm" method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Edit">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form_settings">
                        <p><input id="HeaderStyle" value="@item1.Header" type="text" name="Header" placeholder="Rubrik" required /></p>
                        <p><textarea id="inputTextArea" class="textarea" rows="5" cols="50" name="Content" placeholder="innehåll" required>@item1.Content</textarea></p>

                        <div class="@*radioPosition*@">
                            <input type="radio" name="category" value="KIDS" checked /><label>Kids</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="category" value="TECH" /><label>Tech</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="category" value="GOSSIP" /><label>Gossip</label>
                        </div>
                        <p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span><input asp-route-PostID="@item1.PostID" id="submitPostButton" class="submit" type="submit" value="Save Changes" @*onclick="return validateForm()" *@ /></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried following diffrent guides but without luck. Do I have the wrong approche when using Bind(). Am I missing anything?

Tell me if you want to see anything else from my code. Thanks for all the help I get!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with tage Helpers...